# Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to find the max value in the id column in the table Users using php and mysql.

```
if ($conn->query("SELECT MAX(id) FROM Users ") === TRUE){ 
$max=$conn->query("SELECT MAX(id)  FROM Users");
echo "Max created";
}else {
echo "Error creating Max: " . $conn->error;
}
```

and creating this error:

> creating Max: Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'

What is the problem? I tried using solutions from other threads of the same problem but they didn't help me.

this is the schema of Users:

```
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| users | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: are you sure 'id' is lower case or upper case? 'ID'

Comment: Please include the schema for the `Users` table.

Comment: If you are running Windows then column names should not be case sensitive.

Comment: I'm quite sure that `$conn->query("SELECT MAX(id) FROM Users ") === TRUE` never will valuate as true. `query()` returns false on failure and a result set on success. It never returns true.

Comment: And you're actually trying to execute the query twice, once in the if statement and again if the first was successful. Execute it once, then check the response instead.

Comment: As you can see, there is no id-field in that table so the error message is quite on the nose. Btw, what's the point of that table, if it only contains one field with id's?

Comment: I think it's pretty obvious, wouldn't you agree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$max=$conn->query("SELECT MAX(users) FROM Users");
```

Comment: can you "explain" this?

Comment: `id` was the incorrect column name, `users` was provided by the asker.

Comment: I hope the OP accepts your answer, but fear they either won't or don't know how, seeing their track record on acceptance. Edit: Ah, they accepted it, right on.